# Why is Airflow Scheduler making so many system calls to the DAG files?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, strace

We are trying to find out why our **Airflow Scheduler** is making so many system calls to the DAG files?

We have **Airflow v2.5.3** deployed in AWS with the **Scheduler and Webserver** on the same EC2 instance and multiple **Workers** on their own EC2 instances.  They all share an **EFS provided NFS mount** providing a shared configuration setup (i.e. they all use the same airflow.cfg, DAGs Directory, and Python Environment).

We noticed our **EFS charges** increasing (due to NFS bandwidth usage).  We used **strace** to determine that it was the **Airflow Scheduler** constantly polling the **DAG files**.  When I say constantly, I mean each DAG is being polled via **newfstatat** twice every second. With **63 DAGs** that is **126 calls per second** (for no apparent reason).

In our **airflow.cfg** file we have the following two settings:

```
# min_file_process_interval set for every 2 minutes
min_file_process_interval = 120

# dag_dir_list_interval set for every 5 minutes
dag_dir_list_interval = 300
```

We could see in the **strace** logs precisely when the scheduler was initiating both of the above tasks as there were multiple child processes spawned to handle the **DAG file parsing** in response to **min_file_process_interval** and appropriate lines showing **openat** calls in sync with the **dag_dir_list_interval** timing.  This is all well and good and was to be expected. However, in between these expected events are the constant **newfstatat** calls to each DAG file.

The **strace** command we ran was the following:

```
sudo strace -f -t -e trace=file -p <PID of Airflow Scheduler - DagFileProcessorManager> -Y -yy -T -o strace.log
```

A sampling of the **strace.log** output for a roughly *one second period* (showing the constant system calls to **newfstatat**) is as follows:

```
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/DAG-Number-1.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8640, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000054>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU6-Zabbix-Data-To-Snowflake.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8740, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/BAC_invoicing.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=17227, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-VPI-Create-Tickets.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6576, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-VPI-Alert-Manager.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2338, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Aura-Remove-User.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=14773, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Teams-Migration-Data-Validation.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8339, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-AURA-Teams-Phone-Migration.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4989, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-SBC-DialPlan.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3471, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Aura-One-X-Software.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=5219, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Aura-EC500-Equinox.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6839, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Teams-Migration.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=14682, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-CLI-Ctrl-Test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=10907, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Aura-Desktop-Phone.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=20267, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Avaya.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9181, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-VMWare.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8904, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Cert.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8865, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-HP.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8825, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Suse.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8863, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Microsoft-NVD.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=11018, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Mitel.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8886, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Microsoft-Feed.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8743, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-RSS-Bund-WID.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8706, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Cisco.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8755, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Dell.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8865, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-Vendor_Release_Detail-Workflow.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=12133, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-PRTG-Watchdog_Metric_Collector.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4309, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000049>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-OT-Ticket-Manager-Workflow.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=16262, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-PRTG-Watchdog.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4443, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-OT-NPS-Workflow.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=22145, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-PRTG-Workflow.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=13019, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU3/CU3-MX-ONE-Create-Extension.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=13128, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU3/CU3-MX-ONE-Name-Change.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6140, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU3/CU3-MX-ONE-Check-credentials.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=10817, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU3/CU3-MX-ONE-Delete-Extension.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=7825, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000046>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overmind-Update_Overlord_Keys.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2379, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overmind-Monitor.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3383, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overmind-Update_Overlord_Capabilities.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2643, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overseer-Overlord_Persistence.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2808, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overmind-Teams-Test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3765, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overseer-Collection_Parser.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2015, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overmind-BitBucket.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2920, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-gto_backup.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9056, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000063>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_backup_configs.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9182, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_clear_missing_dags.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4618, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_kill_halted_tasks.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=20250, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-find_long_running_tasks.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6182, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_log_cleanup_PRTG.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=11042, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_log_cleanup.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9093, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_delete_broken_dags.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3216, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Name-Change.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9084, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-CXE-Deactivate-Voicemail.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4490, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Delete-Onephone.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4362, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Create-Extension.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8759, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Delete-Extension.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8574, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Create-Onephone.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6709, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Check-credentials.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=10785, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-AURA-Name-Change.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=10718, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Error-271.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9422, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-VPN-Connect-Atmos-Agent.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=10676, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Error-349.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9295, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Error-268.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9422, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-AURA-Create-Extension.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6055, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/DAG-Number-1.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8640, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000048>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU6-Zabbix-Data-To-Snowflake.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8740, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/BAC_invoicing.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=17227, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-VPI-Create-Tickets.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6576, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-VPI-Alert-Manager.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2338, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Aura-Remove-User.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=14773, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Teams-Migration-Data-Validation.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8339, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-AURA-Teams-Phone-Migration.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4989, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-SBC-DialPlan.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3471, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000063>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Aura-One-X-Software.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=5219, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Aura-EC500-Equinox.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6839, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Teams-Migration.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=14682, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-CLI-Ctrl-Test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=10907, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU1/CU1-Aura-Desktop-Phone.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=20267, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Avaya.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9181, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-VMWare.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8904, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Cert.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8865, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-HP.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8825, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Suse.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8863, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Microsoft-NVD.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=11018, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Mitel.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8886, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Microsoft-Feed.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8743, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-RSS-Bund-WID.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8706, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Cisco.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8755, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Vulnerability/Vulnerability-Dell.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8865, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000046>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-Vendor_Release_Detail-Workflow.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=12133, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-PRTG-Watchdog_Metric_Collector.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4309, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-OT-Ticket-Manager-Workflow.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=16262, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-PRTG-Watchdog.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4443, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-OT-NPS-Workflow.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=22145, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU2/CU2-PRTG-Workflow.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=13019, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU3/CU3-MX-ONE-Create-Extension.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=13128, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU3/CU3-MX-ONE-Name-Change.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6140, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000051>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU3/CU3-MX-ONE-Check-credentials.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=10817, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000049>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU3/CU3-MX-ONE-Delete-Extension.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=7825, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overmind-Update_Overlord_Keys.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2379, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overmind-Monitor.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3383, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overmind-Update_Overlord_Capabilities.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2643, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overseer-Overlord_Persistence.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2808, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overmind-Teams-Test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3765, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overseer-Collection_Parser.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2015, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU4/CU4-Overmind-BitBucket.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=2920, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-gto_backup.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9056, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_backup_configs.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9182, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_clear_missing_dags.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4618, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_kill_halted_tasks.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=20250, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-find_long_running_tasks.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6182, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_log_cleanup_PRTG.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=11042, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_log_cleanup.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9093, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/Maintenance/CU4-Maintenance-airflow_delete_broken_dags.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3216, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Name-Change.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9084, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-CXE-Deactivate-Voicemail.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4490, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Delete-Onephone.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=4362, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Create-Extension.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8759, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Delete-Extension.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8574, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Create-Onephone.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6709, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000045>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Check-credentials.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=10785, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-AURA-Name-Change.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=10718, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Error-271.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9422, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-VPN-Connect-Atmos-Agent.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=10676, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000043>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Error-349.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9295, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-MX-ONE-Error-268.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9422, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000046>
52603<airflow schedul> 19:39:18 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</air1/airflow>, "/air1/airflow/dags/CU5/CU5-AURA-Create-Extension.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6055, ...}, 0) = 0 <0.000044>
```

As a result of these constant calls (which I assume are probably just looking at the **mtime** on each file) our **EFS/NFS Bandwidth** usage is extremely high.  Looking in the **AWS Console** at the **EFS Monitoring** for this particular share we can see **Metadata** outweighing both **Reads** and **Writes** by a disproportionate amount (i.e. METADATA taking 98% of the bandwidth, READS taking 1.95%, and WRITES taking 0.05 ).

For testing and to relive the bandwidth usage we copied the DAGs locally so the scheduler could query locally rather than across the NFS mount.  As soon as we did this the NFS usage dropped and so did the excessive bandwidth charges.  But still, using **strace** we can see the continuous calls occurring (just locally now).

So does anyone have any idea what is going on here?  I checked the [Airflow Release Notes](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/release_notes.html) to see if there was any bug/fix that may address this issue (up to v2.7.3) but saw nothing.  I really see no reason why the scheduler needs to be constantly hitting the DAG files (outside of the two configuration options presented above).

For now I am going to look into using **rsync** to keep the local DAG files in sync with the remote DAG files for now.  But hoping there may be something (maybe a configuration setting) that I can tweak to remedy this situation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Russell